# Why does initial state get modified just once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Initially I have three components in the state and showed in the browser, i want to delete all of them by clicking, but seems to work just the first time, the rest just seems to replace one to another. Why it behaves like that?
[image]

TestCom.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MarkaTest from "./MarkaTest";

function TestCom() {
  const [points, setPoints] = useState([
    <MarkaTest color={"red"} deleteM={deleteRed} />,
    <MarkaTest color={"green"} deleteM={deleteGren} />,
    <MarkaTest color={"yellow"} deleteM={deleteYellow} />,
  ]);
  console.log(points);
  function deleteRed() {
    let g = points.filter((x) => x.props.color !== "red");
    setPoints(g);
  }
  function deleteGren() {
    let g = points.filter((x) => x.props.color !== "green");
    setPoints(g);
  }
  function deleteYellow() {
    let g = points.filter((x) => x.props.color !== "yellow");
    setPoints(g);
  }

  return <div>{points}</div>;
}

export default TestCom;
```

MarkaTest.js

```
import React from "react";

function MarkaTest(props) {
  return (
    <span style={{ background: props.color }} onClick={props.deleteM}>
      Click to delete it
    </span>
  );
}

export default MarkaTest;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-albattani-85r6u?file=/src/TestCom.js

Answer (score 1):

The functions deleteRed, deleteGren and deleteYellow exist in the scope of the original render, so when they reference the variable `points` they are actually referring to the original value of `points`. This is because you assign the functions when you create the component, and you only create the component on the first render (the argument passed to useState is only used on the first render, discarded otherwise). I would do this instead:

```
function TestCom() {
    const [points, setPoints] = useState(["red", "green", "yellow"]);
    console.log(points);

    return (
        <div>
          {points.map((color, index) => (
            <MarkaTest
              key={index}
              color={color}
              deleteM={() => {
                let g = points.filter((x) => x !== color);
                setPoints(g);
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--the functions are created on every render. While I think your solution is *better*, I don't think it's because the functions won't work if they're implemented correctly.

Comment: The functions are created on every render, but only the ones from the first render gets used, since only the *components* that you create on the first render gets used. The value you pass to useState gets discarded on any but the first render, so you never actually recreate the components.

Comment: "I think your solution is better" \*dies inside a little\*

Comment: @Daniel You'll be ok ;) Just cleaner :)

Comment: @ViktorW Ooooh I see; they're in state--you're right, I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using callbacks in your setPoints function instead.
You should never update state directly as you can get undefined behaviour as you were experiencing. Instead create a copy of the state (current in the below example) and modify based on that (filtering)

```js
function TestCom() {
  const [points, setPoints] = React.useState([
    <MarkaTest color={"red"} deleteM={deleteRed} />,
    <MarkaTest color={"green"} deleteM={deleteGren} />,
    <MarkaTest color={"yellow"} deleteM={deleteYellow} />,
  ]);
  console.log(points);
  function deleteRed() {
    setPoints((current) => current.filter((x) => x.props.color !== "red"));
  }
  function deleteGren() {
    setPoints((current) => current.filter((x) => x.props.color !== "green"));
  }
  function deleteYellow() {
    setPoints((current) => current.filter((x) => x.props.color !== "yellow"));
  }

  return <div>{points}</div>;
}

function MarkaTest(props) {
  return (
    <span style={{ background: props.color }} onClick={props.deleteM}>
      Click to delete it
    </span>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode ><TestCom /></React.StrictMode>, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```